# How can I make Cirqus stop automatically creating new instances?

Tags: cqrs, cirqus

I have an aggregate root with a few events and commands. One of those commands is a *CreateCommand*. That command should create a new aggregate root with a given ID. Every other event/command should just update an existing aggregate root and **fail if the aggregate root with the given ID doesn't exist**.

How can I make Cirqus work this way?

This is how I configure my CommandProcessor:

```
                var commandProcessor = CommandProcessor
                    .With()
#if DEBUG
                    .Logging(l =>
                    {
                        if (_useConsoleForLogging)
                        {
                            l.UseConsole(Logger.Level.Debug);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            l.UseDebug(Logger.Level.Debug);
                        }
                    })
#endif
                    .EventStore(e => e.UseSqlServer(_connectionString, _eventsTableName))
                    .EventDispatcher(e => e.UseViewManagerEventDispatcher(viewManagers))
                    .Create();
```

This is the *CreateCommand*:

```
    public class CreateCommand : ExecutableCommand
    { 
        public CreateCommand()
        {
            CreatedGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public Guid CreatedGuid { get; }

        public override void Execute(ICommandContext context)
        {
            var root = context.Create<MyAggregateRoot>(CreatedGuid.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Of course this *CreateCommand* contains more code that emits a few events to immediately update some properties of the created instance, but I've removed them as they're not vital to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using `ExecutableCommand` to implement your own update command - you could call it `UpdateCommand`.

It could look something like this:

```
public abstract class UpdateCommand<TAggregateRoot>
{
    readonly string _aggregateRootId;
    protected UpdateCommand(string aggregateRootId)
    {
        _aggregateRootId = aggregateRootId;
    }

    public override void Execute(ICommandContext context)
    {
        var instance = context.Load<TAggregateRoot>(_aggregateRootId);

        Update(instance);
    }

    public abstract void Update(TAggregateRoot instance);
}
```

and then all commands derived off of `UpdateCommand` would experience exceptions if they tried to address non-existing instances.

Similarly, you could *ensure creation* with a `CreateCommand` base class that would use `ICommandContext`'s `Create<TAggregateRoot>` method to ensure that an existing instance was not accidentally being addressed.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't I lose a lot of performance with this? It has to replay all the events for the given aggregate root on every command. Or does the base *ExecutableCommand* also work this way?

Comment: you'll experience a (ever-so-slight-but-depending-on-length-of-history-of-course) hit for every root instance that you load, no matter how you do it - there's no way with Cirqus (at the moment) to "just append events" to a root's event stream - it may be possible in the future, but noone I know of have had any problems with the way it works

Comment: you can check out the [implementation of the standard generic `Command<TAggregateRoot>`](https://github.com/d60/Cirqus/blob/master/d60.Cirqus/Commands/Command.cs#L43-L68) so see what you're up against :)

Comment: I see... :) The code is about the same except for the Create method. So no performance loss with this *trick*. Thanks! I'll look into caching/snapshotting to avoid bad performance.

Comment: regarding snapshotting - please base your decision of adding this complexity on some actual measurements on command execution time - you can hook up a profiler by going `.Options(o => o.AddProfiler(..))` during the configuration, which you can use to track exactly which root types are slow

Comment: I suggest you start tracking aggregate root load times now (e.g. by using Serilog into some kind of structured format) so you can gather some stats later on to spot the development of the avg load time per aggregate root type over time